# How to get data from Firebase Realtime Database by id in Kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I need to get data from the Realtime Database. I have a `users` node and each user has an ID. How can I get the whole User object from this database?

[image: Realtime Database:]

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the whole User object from this database?

Simply by creating a reference that points to the UID of the user. In code, it will be as simple as:

```
val uid = Firebase.auth.currentUser?.uid
val uidRef = Firebase.database.reference.child("users").child(uid)
uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener {
    if (it.isSuccessful) {
        val snapshot = it.result
        val name = snapshot.child("name").getValue(String::class.java)
        val ocupation = snapshot.child("ocupation").getValue(String::class.java)
        val height = snapshot.child("height").getValue(Long::class.java)
        Log.d(TAG, "$name/$ocupation/$height")
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "${it.exception?.message}") //Never ignore potential errors!
    }
}
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
ggg/ggg/120
```

If you want to get the data as an object of type User, then you have to create a User class:

```
data class User(
    var name: String? = null,
    var ocupation: String? = null,
    var height: Long? = null
)
```

And in code it will look like this:

```
val uid = Firebase.auth.currentUser?.uid
val uidRef = Firebase.database.reference.child("users").child(uid)
uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener {
    if (it.isSuccessful) {
        val user = it.result.getValue(User::class.java)
        Log.d(TAG, "${user.name}/${user.ocupation}/${user.height}")
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "${it.exception?.message}") //Never ignore potential errors!
    }
}
```

The result in the logcat will be the same as above.

Comment: Hey Yunnane. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?